# How to get a json object from CompletionStage in play-framework 2.6

Tags: java, playframework, promise, playframework-2.6, completion-stage

I need to get the json object from the following code

```
JsonObject request = HttpRequestProcessor.getJsonFromRequest(request().body());
    ActorRef actorRef = ActorHandler.getActorReferenceOfParameterisedActor(AControllerTasksExecutor.class,
            new AControllersTaskContext(FactoryType.USER_COMMAND_FACTORY, ObjectType.PURCHASE_SHARES));

            CompletionStage<JsonObject> promise = PromiseHandler.getPromise(actorRef, request, 7000);

    JsonObject response = null;

    Result result = null;
    try {
        response =  promise.get(70000);
        log.debug(">> response object >> {}", response);
        result = PlayResultHandler.getResult(response.get("status").getAsInt(), JsonHandler.parseJsonIntoString(response));

    } catch (Exception e) {

}

public class PromiseHandler {


private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PromiseHandler.class);

public static <B> CompletionStage<B> getPromise(ActorRef actorRef, Object msg, int time) {

    log.debug("Preparing promise. ActorRef: {}, Message-Object: {}, time: {}", actorRef, msg, time);
    CompletionStagev<B> prom = CompletionStage.wrap(ask(actorRef, msg, time)).map(new Function<Object, B>() {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public B apply(Object response) {
            log.debug("In Apply method. Returning Response.  Response-object: {}",response);
            return (B) response;
        }

    });

    return prom;
}
```

}

```
public class AControllerTasksExecutor extends UntypedActor {


    private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(AControllerTasksExecutor.class);

    AControllersTaskContext context = null;

    public AControllerTasksExecutor(AControllersTaskContext context) {

        this.context = context;
    }


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object arg0) throws Exception {

        log.info("Message received. Processing on Message. ");

        Object response = context.executesStrategy(arg0);

        log.debug("Sending response back ");

        getSender().tell(response, getSelf());

    }
```

how can i get the json object i am doing it like

```
response =  promise.get(70000);
```

but it gives

```
cannot find symbol
[error]   symbol:   method get(int)
[error]   location: variable promise of type java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage<com.google.gson.JsonObject>
[error]             response =  promise.get(70000);
```

how can i achieve this ?

Comment: can you update the question with an excerpt from the JSON you're trying to parse?

Comment: its the compile time error i am getting,,before parsiong the json which happens at the run time

Comment: it seems to me this line is unfinished `ActorRef actorRef = ActorHandler.getActorReference`, can u post the full line?

Comment: i did edited  the code and the AcontrollerTask actor as well

Comment: can you check if your promise object not null?